# Force magit to ask for confirmation before deleting a branch

Tags: magit, config

I would like to have magit ask for confirmation when I've told it to delete a particular branch.

Currently it seems that magit considers the selection of a branch to delete to be the confirmation, as the documentation to `magit-no-confirm` says:

> The user always has to confirm the deletion of a branch by
> accepting the default choice (or selecting another branch)

This is not enough of a confirmation for me, and I'd like to make magit ask me for confirmation *after* I've selected a branch to delete.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting some more context from the documentation:

> `delete-unmerged-branch' Once a branch has been deleted it can
> only be restored using low-level recovery tools provided by
> Git.  And even then the reflog is gone.  The user always has
> to confirm the deletion of a branch by accepting the default
> choice (or selecting another branch), but when a branch has
> not been merged yet, also make sure the user is aware of that.

In other words, if you enable this option, then Magit *will* ask for confirmation before deleting an *unmerged branch*. It won't do so for merged branches, because doing that by accident is much less dangerous.